# What are the Issues with this relational database schema?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

[image]

I'm asked to design a relational database to keep data to answer clinic operation queries such as:

● List the patient appointments for each doctor for a given date.

● When a patient rings to make an appointment, give the available time slots for a given date.

● Retrieve the address of patients to send notices via mail services.

I have one database schema of one relation as shown below:

**ABC(doc-name, doc-gender, registration_num, qualification, pat-name, pat-gender, DOB, address, phone-num, appoint-date, appoint-time, type)**

I understand that it's generally not a good idea to keep all the information in one table because of the possibility of duplicates so I made three tables instead:

**DOC(name, gender, registration_num, qualification)**

**PAT(name, gender, DOB, address, phone_num)**

**APPOINT(date, time, type)**

Are there any other issues with this design? Should I get rid of type?

Thank you

Comment: What is `type` for? That seems very wrong.

Comment: It refers to the duration of the appointment, I am thinking of removing it because it's too vague.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. The type of the value is going to be the same for all records and the actual value will not likely align with the difference in storage sizes. It is not vague, it is both unnecessary and inapplicable.

Comment: Do you have the business rules for the clinic in question?  If not, that's where you need to start.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. PS Time to read a textbook re database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

The way how you have normalized (split) the data into three tables looks reasonable already.

The following you could consider:

- Doctor & Patient IDs
- Appointment Datetime
- Primary Keys

**Doctor & Patient IDs**
The names of patients are not unique and this doesn't have to be for names of doctors as well, therefore I would suggest to add a new column in in the DOC and PAT tables for an ID. These IDs should be added to the APPOINT table, to link one doctor and one patient to the appointment.

**Appointment Datetime**
It is easier to calculate times and days in SQL, when you are using the respective DATETIME objects of your database system instead of splitting date and time into two different columns.
Instead of type, I would suggest to calculate a new field for the end time of the appointment as well. This makes calculating available time slots of doctors easier.

**Primary Keys**
Every table should have a primary key, which is unique for the table.
In case of the doctor and patient this could be the ID.
In case of a appointment this could be the doctor's ID and the start time of the appointment, because they have to be unique.

The schema is not complete. I have added just the details for the columns, which I have mentioned above.

```
DOC:  
- id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  
- name  
- gender  
- registration_num  
- qualification  
- PRIMARY KEY (id)

PAT:  
- id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  
- name  
- gender  
- dob  
- address  
- phone_num  
- PRIMARY KEY (id)

APPOINT:  
- doc_id INT NOT NULL  
- pat_id INT NOT NULL  
- start DATETIME NOT NULL  
- end DATETIME NOT NULL  
- PRIMARY KEY (doc_id, start_datetime)
```